# Is it recommended to create an API for internal services?

Tags: rest

I'm working on a project that consists in an python script that get data from an API and calculate things based in this data. The goal is to get this calculated information to a website. I was thinking in doing something like running this code in the same server as the website host server and posting the data generated in a database, then the website would get the information from the database and display it in the website. However, the front-end developer that is working with me said that would be a better option to develop a REST Api that would return to the website the data calculated in the python script. Does it makes sense to develop an API that will only be used internally? Wouldn't it be another unnecessary factor of complexity, since the data could be calculated, stored and retrieved form the host server without any API?

Comment: If you can be 100% sure the functionality won't be used by any other app, and the site itself won't switch to another DB/framework ever, then sure, use direct DB call. Otherwise creating a rest api today is saving you from tomorrow headaches https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277701/why-do-people-do-rest-apis-instead-of-dbals